# Beacons scanning stopped with CoreBluetooth library

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, beacon, eddystone

I am using `CoreBluetooth` library to scan my `Eddystone` beacons.

Exactly, I am using this class from `google/Eddystone` repo

https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/tools/ios-eddystone-scanner-sample/EddystoneScannerSampleSwift/BeaconScanner.swift

Is there any reason why the `CoreBluetooth` stop scanning my beacons suddenly after a while of starting?

Comment: what are the conditions when this happens?  is the app in the foreground or background?  does the app continue to run otherwise?

Comment: It happens suddenly, after `didLoseBeacon` function has been called, all work is on the foreground, yes the app continues to run without any problem. even `didDisconnectPeripheral` and `didFailToConnect` functions aren't calling.

Comment: After this happens, if you use [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) does it detect the beacon?

Comment: Yes, all beacons are still visible by the app

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the Google BeaconScanner class.  After it stops, can you force your code to call beaconScanner.startScanning(); to see if it starts working again?

Comment: Nevermind, it was a problem with my iPhone, I change it and everything works fine. Thank you